# WordPress Search Query Issues

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having issues with the default WordPress search bar. The search bar no longer brings up any related post results. Sorting by categories also just results in being sent to blank template pages instead of redirecting to the 404 page.

I haven't been able to find any useful answers or tutorials on how to even begin approaching fixing a broken search bar. All the tutorials just say to install search plugins like Relevanssi, which I tried and it didn't help.

If anyone knows how search query code works in WordPress, any info would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

This is the website link and searchform.php in question, if that helps any. https://www.animationpagoda.com/

```
<?php
/**
 * Searchform
 *
 * Custom template for search form
 */
 ?>

 <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="collapse">
            <div class="large-8 mobile-three columns">
                <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Write a keyword...', 'magneti' ); ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 mobile-one columns">
                <input type="submit" class="button prefix" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: You can paste you search.php of your theme in your question..

Comment: Paste your code here, I think you've changed the search query ! Take a look here https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: that's not search page.. search.php not searchform.php

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had to create a new search.php file and duplicate the page.php info into it.  There are still some formatting and filter issues that will need to be worked out, but the initial question has been resolved.